# Xcode Link UnityFramwork with Firebase: Undefined symbol:_FIRInstallationIDDidChangeNotification

Tags: xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

[the Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESO3T.jpg)

I have searched and tried

1. File -> Add Package -> Install Firebase
2. `Other Linker Flags`，Add `-ObjC，-framework，$(inherited)`
3. `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` = `"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources"`
4. `Build Active Architectures Only` set `NO`

Can anyone help? plz

If you need more info ,plz let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by [Firebase with Unity causing Linker Error in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465916/firebase-with-unity-causing-linker-error-in-xcode)

and reinstall firebase arrcording this video https://youtu.be/sKKbUDNOHC0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).